# I can't change column values in Gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to insert an autonumber column into a datagridview control in C#.

Everything works well, but I can't write anything to the column. It remains empty.

How can I fix this?

Below is my code (grv - gridview, ds-dataset):

```
        grv1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        grv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];        
        grv1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "LastName";


        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nrCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        nrCol.Name = "Nr";
        nrCol.HeaderText = "Nr";
        grv.Columns.Insert(0, nrCol);
        grv.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;


        for (int i=0;i<grv.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            grv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i.ToString();       
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have rows in your grid? I see code that adds a column, and a loop that changes the field for every present row, but I don't see code that adds rows.

You need to call `grv.Rows.Add(...)` with a pre-filled `DataGridViewRow` within your loop.

Comment: yes, i have rows, which are read from the dataset : grv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: Then I suggest you update your code sample to match the actual code you use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `find the control` and `assign the value to the Text property of TextBox control`  (not to the cell) ***after binding the data source***; Cell value may not be visible since TextBox is covering it...

```
//your code here
...
//assign data source (if you have any)
grv.DataSource = YourDataSource;
//bind the gridview
grv.DataBind();

//now you can loop through the gridview as below
for (int i=0;i<grv.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)grv.Rows[i].FindControl("Nr");
    txt.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

***Or*** you can do this neatly as below;

***Code behind:***

```
//define index variable in the code behind
protected int index = 1;
```

***HTML:***

```
<!--Add this column to the GridView with your text box -->
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Nr" text='<%# index ++ %>'></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that it is desktop application, not ASP.NET. I don't have some methods like DataBind or FindControl available

Comment: In that case you should assign the datasource after adding the column and before looping through.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you have Person Table or something like that. You don't need to create a `autonumber` for that table in that way, just set the `primary key` and `auto-increment = true` of that table from your database and done.

**UPDATE**

Just read your comment, this is the good solution for your problem. [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Comment: It's true but I'm using a selection of some records from my table on SQL server and sorting the by names. If I used table key I would have numbers like 5467, 3412, 7896 and so on and I want it to be 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people, I solved the problem myself, in a bit dirty way.

This rownumber is handy, I added it to my tricks ;)

But what I did this time was binding my created datagrid collumn to some random collumn from dataset. When it was unbound, I couldn't write anything. When it was bound I easily overwrote the values

```
    grv1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    grv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];        
    grv1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "LastName";


    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nrCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    nrCol.Name = "Nr";
    nrCol.HeaderText = "Nr";
    grv1.Columns.Insert(0, nrCol);
    grv1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;

    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    grv1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Postal code"; //or whatever existing column 


    for (int i=0;i<grv.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        grv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i.ToString();       
    }
```